Bounding the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Big|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\Big|^2\,dx$
Is there a functional inequality that allows me to bound $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left\vert\,{\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(0\right)}{x}}\,\right\vert^2\,dx$$ in terms of a Sobolev norm of $f$, say?
If $f$ is equal to its Taylor series at $0$, we have $f(0)=f(x)-xf'(x)+\frac{x^2}{2}f''(x)-...$, so $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=f'(x)-\frac{x}{2}f''(x)+\frac{x^2}{3!}f'''(x)-...,$$ but I can't see that this helps very much as this contains infinitely many derivatives of $f$.

Have a look at the remainder in Taylor’s theorem.

Since you want a bound, I'm guessing the integral is definite. By $\int_x$, which integration range do you intend?

@J.G. integral over the whole space $\mathbb R$

Are there any conditions on $f$ except that integration is defined for it?

Write
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \int_0^1\, f'(xu)\, du.
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{align*}
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty\biggl( \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}\biggr)^2\, dx 
 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty
 \biggl( \int_0^1\, f'(xu)\, du \biggr)
 \biggl( \int_0^1\, f'(xv)\, dv \biggr)
 \, dx \\
 &=
 \int_0^1\,
 \int_0^1\,
 \biggl(
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty
 f'(xu)
 f'(xv)
 \, dx 
        \biggr) 
 \, du
 \, dv  \\
 &\leq
 \int_0^1\,
 \int_0^1\,
 \biggl(
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty\, (f'(xu))^2\, dx
 \biggr)^{1/2}
 \biggl(
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty\, (f'(xv))^2\, dx
 \biggr)^{1/2}
 \, du
 \, dv,
\end{align*}
the final line following from the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.
The substitution $\xi := xu$ in the first of the final two inner integrals shows
\begin{align*}
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty\, (f'(xu))^2\, dx
 &= u^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\, (f'(\xi))^2\, d\xi \\
 &= u^{-1}\Vert f'\Vert^2
\end{align*}
and similarly for the second
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty\, (f'(xv))^2\, dx
 = v^{-1}\Vert f'\Vert^2.
\end{equation*}
It follows
\begin{align*}
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty\biggl( \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}\biggr)^2\, dx 
 &\leq
 \Vert f'\Vert^2\int_0^1\int_0^1\, u^{-1/2} v^{-1/2}\, du\, dv \\
 &= 4\Vert f'\Vert^2.
\end{align*}

this is brilliant! Does it work in higher dimensions? What if the integral is over $\mathbb R^n$?

also does this inequality have a name?

@schrodingerscat: I’m afraid I don’t know.

When I try to generalize this proof to $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, I get $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{|x|}\right)^2~\mathrm{d}x \leq |\nabla f|_{L^2} \int_0^1\int_0^1 u^{-n/2}v^{-n/2}~\mathrm{d}u~\mathrm{d}v. $$ The remaining integral only converges for $n=1$.

@schrodingerscat If this answers your question, you may accept it.
